# FOSRestBundle : Difference between RequestParam and QueryParam

Tags: php, rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

I don't understand the difference between the @QueryParam et the @RequestParam annotation with FOSRestBundle (Example : https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/param_fetcher_listener.html).

Do you have any mean to know which one I have to use to declare my API parameters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends on what you want to achieve with your API endpoints. Basically [`QueryParam`](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Controller/Annotations/QueryParam.php#L17) represents a parameter that must be present in **GET** data (so we're talking about query string parameters) while [`RequestParam`](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Controller/Annotations/RequestParam.php#L17) represents a parameter that must be present in **POST** or **PUT** data (which means parameters in the body of the request).